# Android JSON POST and then response

Tags: android, json

I can retrieve data through `JSON` in `listview` but I want to show data relative to the user logged in so for that I have to Post username to `PHP` script. I don't have any idea how to post the username to `PHP` script and then get respond from web server.

```
private class GetFixture extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg) {


        ServiceHandler serviceClient = new ServiceHandler();
        Log.d("url: ", "> " + URL_ITEMS);
        String json = serviceClient.makeServiceCall(URL_ITEMS,ServiceHandler.GET);
        // print the json response in the log
        Log.d("Get match fixture resps","> " + json);
        if (json != null) {
            try {
                Log.d("try", "in the try");
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
                Log.d("jsonObject", "new json Object");
                // Getting JSON Array node
                matchFixture = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_FIXTURE);
                Log.d("json aray", "user point array");
                int len = matchFixture.length();
                Log.d("len", "get array length");
                for (int i = 0; i < matchFixture.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = matchFixture.getJSONObject(i);
                    String matchId = c.getString(TAG_MATCHID);
                    Log.d("matchId", matchId);
                    String teamA = c.getString(TAG_TEAMA);
                    Log.d("teamA", teamA);
                    String teamB = c.getString(TAG_TEAMB);
                    Log.d("teamB", teamB);
                    //  hashmap for single match
                    HashMap<String, String> matchFixture = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    matchFixture.put(TAG_MATCHID, matchId);
                    matchFixture.put(TAG_TEAMA, teamA);
                    matchFixture.put(TAG_TEAMB, teamB);
                    matchFixtureList.add(matchFixture);
                }
            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.d("catch", "in the catch");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("JSON Data", "Didn't receive any data from server!");
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                Doctor_Names.this, matchFixtureList,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[] {
                TAG_MATCHID, TAG_TEAMA,TAG_TEAMB
        }
                , new int[] {
                R.id.teamA,R.id.name,
                R.id.teamB
        }
        );
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

sir this code perfectly show me all data from this server but i want some specific data like i want to show data related to the person who is logged in so for that i have to pass the user name to `PHP` script so dont have idea to `POST` any thing to web on the basis of which i can filter data

Comment: You need to ask a more specific question, what do you have so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: Duplicate of [Performing get/post from server for JSON response in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31305631/performing-get-post-from-server-for-json-response-in-android) and dozens others. Did you even search?

Answer (score 4):

**Here is an example**:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("username", "YourUser");
HttpUrlConnectionJson.sendHTTPData("http://" + serverAddress + "/api/SomeUserMethod", obj);
```

**HttpUrlConnectionJson class**

```
public class HttpUrlConnectionJson {

    private static final String TAG = "HttpUrlConnectionJson";

    public static String sendHTTPData(String urlpath, JSONObject json) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            URL url=new URL(urlpath);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            OutputStreamWriter streamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
            streamWriter.write(json.toString());
            streamWriter.flush();
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
                String response = null;
                while ((response = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(response + "\n");
                }
                bufferedReader.close();

                Log.d(TAG, stringBuilder.toString());
                return stringBuilder.toString();
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, connection.getResponseMessage());
                return null;
            }
        } catch (Exception exception){
            Log.e(TAG, exception.toString());
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (connection != null){
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this help